# Raspberry Pi Pico powered by a bike dynamo

Tags: gps, dynamo, raspberry-pi-pico

I am building a GPS tracker for my bike using a Raspberry Pi Pico and a NEO-6M GPS module.

I need this GPS to be up and running at least 14 hours a day.
The only problem is the power source. Ideally given the Pico’s power consumption and the NEO-6M’s one, I’d need something like 1190 mAh for 14h. Since I’m aiming to have some battery autonomy, and also a compact solution (to be easily hidable) I was thinking of using a bike dynamo and hiding the hardware inside a front lamp.
Though I don't know if a dynamo can charge enough a lithium battery (not to power directly the electronics, but to charge day by day the battery) since the unstable dynamo’s output.

What is one way to make this work?

Comment: Welcome! Check the open circuit voltage at max speed and short circuit current and report back.

Comment: @winny I haven't yet the physical hardware, since I am still planning how to organize this, so I am not able to measure the ope circuit voltage at max speed, nor the short circuit current. Though, I know i'm gonna use a ups hat for 18650 (rechargeable) batteries. 
Something like this:
[ups-module](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61XY1DcuUkL._AC_SX679_.jpg)

Comment: Then it’s impossible to answer your question.

Comment: How did you arrive at 1190mAh? Over 14h, that suggests 85mA average current, which sounds like it could be lowered. Also, what voltage are you talking about? 1190mAh is not a measure of energy, after all. Finally, you'll need to know how long the dynamo will be active to charge your battery.

Comment: the Raspberry Pi Pico operates at 3.3V and, under my conditions, uses about 30-40 mA; the NEO-6M GPS module also operates at around 3.3V and uses about 45 mA under normal operating conditions. 
I've found rechargeable batteries with 9900mAh capacity with a 3.7V
As for the dynamo, It would be used for about 30mins everyday, but again, even charging little (to nothing) everyday would be fine

Comment: Why would the dynamo be in use 30 mins per day, while the Gps 14 hrs?

Comment: I leave my bike parked over night, and the next morning it would be nice to find it where I left it.